# How to repair a (2D) NetLogo model that was accidentally saved in NetLogo 3D?

Tags: netlogo

I've been working on a model in netlogo 2D (6.0.4) and accidentally opened the model in 3D. It worked in 3D, so I continued editing the code. I saved it with the same extension (by default) of .nlogo. Now I can't open it in either the 2D or 3D version of netlogo. Any tips to avoid going back to my last iteration of the model (quite a bit of work) or to view the code? I can view it to some degree in a text viewer, but it's not easily interpretable.

Many thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So only a couple of things are different in the file format from 2D to 3D.  The version section will be set to 3D and the `GRAPHICS-WINDOW` widget entry will be changed to handle the extra axis.

Open up the file in a good text editor and swap:

```
@#$#@#$#@
NetLogo 3D 6.0.4
```

with:

```
@#$#@#$#@
NetLogo 6.0.4
```

Then find the `GRAPHICS-WINDOW` entry.  You need to remove a couple numbers here:

```
0 
0
1
1
1
ticks
30.0
```

Count backwards from `ticks` and remove the 4th and 5th lines you see (here they are `0` and `0`).  There should be no spaces or blank lines when you're done, like the rest of the `GRAPHICS-WINDOW` section.

Save it, and you should hopefully be good to go in 2D NetLogo again.  Your view may be moved around a bit, but you can re-edit it to where it was before.

Comment: @DanielBarrios-O'Neill - if Jasper's answer has sorted you out, please click the little check mark next to their answer to mark this question as closed.